# VB6 reference confusion

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I am a .NET Developer.  I have a good understanding of how references work in .NET i.e. if you want to use AssemblyA.ClassA.MethodA in AssemblyB.classB.MethodB then you add a reference in Assembly A to Assembly B.

I am looking at a VB6 app and I get an error when I open it i.e. Errors during load.  Refer to frmMain.log.  I open frmMain.log and it says: "2142: Class MSComDlg.CommonDialog of control CommonDialog1 was not a loaded control class.".  I have used WinMerge to compare the source code in the faulty project to a previous version of the project (which does not have the problem).  The only difference is that the faulty project contains the following line in the client.vdp file:

```
Reference=*\G{08DBEFD7-6A19-4DCE-A533-5BDBB93683C8}#1.2#0#..\..\..\..\..\Windows\SysWOW64\Comdlg32.oca#Microsoft Common Dialog Control 6.0 (SP3)
```

Removing this line seems to resolve the problem.  Why does this resolve the problem?

---

I have used Winmerge to compare yesterdays revision of the project (which does not have the problem) to todays revision of the project (which does have the problem). The only difference is the reference in the original post in the VBP file.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149429

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that someone installed the development version of this control on a different machine and then set a reference to it. When you try to open the project on your machine the reference fails. Or the control was uninstalled. It seems that the project was not using the reference and that it can be safely removed as it will still compile without the reference.

However, I have seen vb6 actually remove non-licensed controls from the form in question in this situation. So it may be that you can now compile because the form is missing a component that was there previously. Have you checked that frmMain has not changed, both the .frm and .frx files?